# NullPointerException at MainFragment

Tags: java, android, android-webview

recently in google analytics I found, that my Android application crashes for some users with NullPointerException. Maybe someone could help me to identify, what makes application crash... Here is crash:

```
NullPointerException (@MainFragment$3:loadFromAssetsWhite:501) {WebViewCoreThread}
```

Here is code from 501 line:

```
private WebResourceResponse loadFromAssetsWhite(String assetPath, String mimeType, String encoding){

            AssetManager assetManager = getActivity().getAssets();
            InputStream input;
            try {
                input = assetManager.open("search-white.png");
                return new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, encoding, input);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("WEB-APP", "Error loading " + assetPath + " from assets: " +
                        e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Here is call for that line:

```
if (webViewUrl != null && webViewUrl.contains("results.html")) {
                        return loadFromAssetsBlack("", "", "");
                    } else {
                        return loadFromAssetsWhite("", "", "");
                    }
```

Comment: Can you please paste the code of getActivity() method.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the exact line that is line number 501.  Whatever object(s) you're accessing properties or methods on at that line, those are your culprits.  For example, if it's this line:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getActivity().getAssets();
```

Then it's the result of `getActivity()` which is either an Activity reference or null.  If it's null, it's because the method is called before the fragment is attached to the activity or after the fragment has been detached but is still alive.

Comment: Hello @Rich, 501 line is: 
`private WebResourceResponse loadFromAssetsWhite(String assetPath, String mimeType, String encoding){`

Comment: Then there should be a "caused by" line in the stack trace.  Post the entire stack trace, and we should know right away what the culprit is.

Comment: I would like to have Stack trace , but I havent have it.

You can see what I have:
[link]http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/204777/1e87afafbc967c08b3c29a968c6add0c

Thats all :( @Rich

Comment: I see what you're saying.  You only get this crash report from Google Analytics.  Are you using Crashlytics as well?  If so, you'd probably have a much more detailed report.

Comment: I applied few days ago for Crashlytics, but still waiting for invite/approval.